# how to design a highly perfoemance database query to do the following?

Tags: database-design

Given 3 tables, students(id, name) , courses(id, name) , grades(id, course_id, student_id, grade), find the top 100 students based on their average grades sorted descendingly by the average grade and in case multiple students have the same average grade, sort them lexicographically in ascending order by their names. Your query should output a table with the following columns (name, average_grade).

i wrote this query

```
SELECT 
    s.name AS name, AVG(g.grade) AS average_grade
FROM
    grades g
        JOIN
    students s ON g.student_id = s.id
GROUP BY g.student_id , s.name
ORDER BY AVG(g.grade) DESC , s.name
LIMIT 100;
```

but it's killed as it 's too slow anyway to improve it ?

Comment: this looks like homewortk, you must give it a try

Comment: i  really gave it but i couldn't solve it

Comment: show us waht you havem, create three tables and try your best and show us all your work in a dbfiddle.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! Homework is **not** off-topic here, **on condition** that a) you tell us it's homework and b) you have made **some sort** of attempt yourself. You should, at least, provide us with a fiddle - with data and your desired result from that data - also, put the DDL and DML from the fiddle here also.

Comment: Yes it 's homework I tried to make a select use of join and group by statements but i couldn't combine all together ! @Vérace  and thanks for you

Comment: Give us tables and sample data in a fiddle for your 3 given tables - as I showed in the link to my last comment! Then JOIN student with grade and course with grade and go from there... Provide at least **something** for us to work with!

Answer (score 0):

could do something like this

SELECT TOP 100 [s].[Name] As [Student Name],AVG([g].[grade]) as [Average Grade]
    FROM [grades] [g]
    join [students] [s] on
 
         [g].[student_id] = [s].[id]
     GROUP BY [g].[student_id],[s].[name]
     ORDER BY AVG([g].[grade]) desc,[s].[name]

Comment: is this mysql ? and thanks for your contribution

Comment: Sorry no, its mssql but i think it should work in mysql except for 'top 100' remove that and add "limit 100" after [Average Grade]

Comment: SELECT [s].[Name] As [Student Name],AVG([g].[grade]) as [Average Grade] limit 100
FROM [grades] [g]
join [students] [s] on
[g].[student_id] = [s].[id]
GROUP BY [g].[student_id],[s].[name]
ORDER BY AVG([g].[grade]) desc,[s].[name] ,,  run this and it doesn't work ?

Comment: The LIMIT goes in the end of the query. Also get rid of the square brackets.